# Unicenta OPOS error SSL

Tags: java, mysql, ssl

Estoy tratando de configurar unicenta pero me aparece el siguiente error, la base de datos esta creada en mysql pero es como si no tuviera acceso ayuda por favor.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 2 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la base de datos esta creada? y el servicio mysql esta arriba?

Comment: Si la base de datos esta creada y el servidor esta arriba

Answer (score 0):

Solución alternativa, del foro de desarrolladores (no recomendado):

Cambie a Java a SE [Runtime Environment 8u211](https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html) o agregue?useSSL=no

Solución alternativa, por azul (recomendado):

Editar (como administrador) archivo: / Editar (como administrador) el archivo:
Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301\lib\security\java.security

Desactive las líneas SSL, guarde los cambios y reinicie la PC: / Y desactive las líneas SSL, guarde los cambios y reinicie el PC:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Después de los cambios y reiniciar, Unicenta ahora podrá conectarse: / Después de los cambios y reinicio, Unicenta ya podrá conectarse:

solución [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://gitlab.com/maravento/uniopos)